# Is it possible to dual boot Ubuntu SERVER and Windows 10 home?

Tags: dual-boot, server

I have Windows 10 Home up already, and I want to dual boot Ubuntu Server 18.04 with it, but looking around there doesn't seem to be ANY tutorials to do this.

I see there are plenty of Ubuntu Desktop and Windows 10 though.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Both systems need to be in same boot mode. And both systems install in the mode you boot installer UEFI or BIOS. there now are two server install versions. With 18.04.1 are several updates to make the gui version more complete. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Server

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the differences between ubuntu server and desktop don't have anything to do with the boot manager (grub), and as long as the boot manager can handle a dual-boot aware install and boot process, it will work fine.

[What's the difference between desktop and server? | Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F)

I suspect the main difficulty you will encounter is just that Ubuntu server appears to use a console-driven install (not a GUI), so the installation process might be targeted towards the advanced user.

It's worth noting (as someone who dual boots Windows and Ubuntu) that you will need to make sure secure boot is disabled in the BIOS, and as you toggle that you will trigger Windows bitlocker disk recovery the next time you boot Windows. If you don't have your Windows bitlocker key ready, you will have lost that particular Windows installation - possibly a nasty surprise. So make sure you have a good backup, good Windows installation media, and your Windows disk recovery key before you start. There are tutorials for that all over the web and since it's Windows it's best not addressed here.

Good luck

Comment: The Ubuntu Server installer has the same options screens & overall install process as the Ubuntu Desktop installer.  The only difference is that the server installer displays the menus in text mode and the desktop installer displays the menus in graphics mode.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Hardy has a good point about backing up the information. I have a dual boot system. After you have backed up all of your information, [make a live CD.](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu#0)Then change your partition. I recommend some software called Gparted. Here is a screenshot of my partition:

[image: Partition] Ext4 is Linux, and NTFS is Windows. OK, after you have done the partitioning, you can finally do the installing. Do Windows first, followed by Ubuntu. Here is a step by step tutorial I found on how to use [Gparted](https://www.lifewire.com/use-gparted-to-partition-hard-drive-2205693) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Partitioning is exactly the problem I am having now. In a previous Win 8.1/16.04 server build, 16.04 server was intuitive and it had an option to install on the largest free space I had. Now, I don't get it. (https://bit.ly/2PiafOT) (https://bit.ly/2MQIo6W) (https://bit.ly/2L3Yatw) (https://bit.ly/2Mzc8bF)

Comment: Here is my original partitions on my disk. I want to install on the inallocated space but for Ubuntu to recognize I need 2 primary partitions, but it wont let me create as one. (http://prntscr.com/kjts1w)

Comment: Thank you for the reply though, I'm going to look at gparted.

Comment: Did you use a live CD to try to create the partition? The computer won't let you change a partition that your already using but you can with a live CD. I have to leave soon, but if your still having trouble when I get back I'll try to help.

Comment: @peteubuntu - Did you get your issues resolved? If there is anything else I can do to help let me know.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to dual win 10 and Ubun 18.04 server, so instead I went with Luuntu 18.04 minimum install since I reasoned I only needed to have around 40 concurrent users on the  webserver anyway and it "hopefully" it should run smoothly and take too much resources with the what I want to do. Thank you kindly for your help.