# trying to install Ubuntu Server on partition of Win10 drive in offline computer

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, offline

Setup:  I am very new to Linux and am looking for detailed steps, please.  I have a internal HDD with Win10 installed on a computer with no internet access.  I have an empty 80Gb partition where I would like to do a dual-boot install of Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS. I have the offline image: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/jammy-preinstalled-server-amd64.img.xz

From the BIOS, I can boot the USB and get the server running in text mode.

$lsblk

| NAME | MAJ:MIN | BN | SIZE | RQ | TYPE | MOUNT POINT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| loop0 | 7:0 | 0 | 63.9M | 1 | loop | /snap/core20/2105 |
| loop1 | 7:1 | 0 | 111.9M | 1 | loop | /snap/lxd/24322 |
| loop2 | 7:2 | 0 | 40.4M | 1 | loop | /snap/snapd/20671 |
| sda | 8:0 | 0 | 2.7T | 0 | disk |  |
| sdb | 8:16 | 0 | 279.5G | 0 | disk |  |
| -sdb1 | 8:17 | 0 | 199G | 0 | part |  |
| -sdb2 | 8:18 | 0 | 1K | 0 | part |  |
| -sdb3 | 8:19 | 0 | 516M | 0 | part |  |
| -sdb5 | 8:21 | 0 | 80G | 0 | part |  |
| sdc | 8:32 | 0 | 117.2G | 0 | disk | / |
| -sdc1 | 8:33 | 1 | 117.1G | 0 | part |  |
| -sdc2 | 8:34 | 1 | 4M | 0 | part |  |
| -sdc3 | 8:35 | 1 | 4M | 0 | part |  |
| -sdc4 | 8:36 | 1 | 106M | 0 | part | /boot/efi |

sdc is my bootable usb and sdb5 is my empty partition.

In Windows I went to disk manager and got:
[disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB9PX.jpg) which has the 80GB drive as RAW.

I can run the server from USB boot. I also have an .img file. I do not have internet access on this computer.

What I want to know is: How can I get Ubuntu-Server on to the sbd5 partition, such that it will be seen by BIOS boot?

Thanks
update: would it make sense to just install all normally on a different, internet-connected computer and then backup the drive and restore it on the offline computer?

Comment: A curious install approach. To play with an Ubuntu Server for learning purposes (no network), WSL or a VM seems a much easier way. For a real, functional server install, you won't be dual-booting and should use the normal interactive Server installer.

Comment: This will be a functional, home, local-only network media server, I will be using $$ Windows programs to create some of the content and wanted to do dual-boot for my convenience.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to dual boot Ubuntu SERVER and Windows 10 home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066270/is-it-possible-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-server-and-windows-10-home)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting yourself up for certain failure. I would strongly recommend not to try the most unorthodox approach ever. Instead, use the recommended methods how to install Ubuntu.

If your first goal is to get familiar with the Linux world, why not install it in a virtual machine first, like VirtualBox or VMWare? That way you don't even need to dual boot, you can simply leave your Windows running and run Ubuntu as a guest in a virtual machine. Remember to make snapshots of that VM (both VirtualBox and VMWare have that capability). Then you can experiment with Ubuntu, and when you manage to misconfigure something, you can revert to the last working snapshot.

Yes, filesystems like Btrfs and ZFS have that capability, too, but the virtualization solutions have an easy-to-use GUI for it.